# '' или «»? Какие кавычки лучше?

Tags: кавычки

Какие кавычки лучше использовать, когда говоришь о том, что то или иное слово значит: одинарные ('') или обычные («»)? У Лопатина в справочнике используются в данном случае первые, то бишь одинарные.

`Слово «Nabel» – oчень нередкое – обозначает 'пупок, navel' / «пупок, navel».`